# Mysql decrease column length possible problems

Tags: mysql

How bad consequences can be when decreasing column length? (i.e. varchar)

I have found this question increasing length possible problems...

[Possible consequences of increasing varchar length in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100254/possible-consequences-of-increasing-varchar-length-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If for example in a username column of type `VARCHAR(32)` there are usernames like `ThisIsMyStupidUsername` and you change it to `VARCHAR(16)`, that username would be cut off and turn into `ThisIsMyStupidUs`.

As long as you make sure there are no records using the space you're cutting off, and there is no situation in which it will have to be used, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. 

Do you know what would happened with transition from int to tinyint where content cannot fit?